# Vim's `:compiler gcc` has an issue with `make: ***`

Tags: c++, c, vim, neovim

It seems to be that Vim's `:compiler gcc` has a bug. It treats `make: ***` as an error and therefor opens an empty buffer named `build.make` when opening quickfix.
Here is a screenshot: [image]

I don't want to bother Vim people for no reason. It looks like a bug to me, but maybe I a m wrong, so I want a second opinion: who else thinks its a bug?

Comment: You should report issues you found to https://github.com/vim/vim/issues or to vim_dev mailing list in case of doubt (whether it's a bug or not).
PS: I never use `gcc` compiler plugin as the default value for `efm` is already tuned for gcc error messages.

Comment: I don't want to bother Vim people for no reason. It looks like a bug to me, but maybe I a m wrong, so I want a second opinion: who else thinks its a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually opened an issue at Vim's Github. Here is the link: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7536. TL;DR - since I use `cmake` and not `make`, `:compiler gcc` was not working as expected, I should have used `:compiler cmake` (such a thing does not exists).